# How to use downloadsvn fa

Tags: svn, google-code

I am unable to download source code files from google code for this project https://code.google.com/p/mytracks/ I am using DownlaodSVN for this. it working fine for projects which has svn. Download svn workes with this project http://stardroid.googlecode.com/svn/ and i was able to downlaod all the files. I need a step by step guide for downloading source files from goolgecode

Answer (score 0):

It seems that mytracks is a mercurial repository and not svn, as found on their [website](https://code.google.com/p/mytracks/source/checkout).  To download:

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/mytracks/
```

Comment: I did look for a .zip or .tgz file and did not find one.  I guess it is a good time to download mercurial (hg), which can be found [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/).